# How to highlight multiple search results in input multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, textarea

I have been trying to highlighting multiple search result hits in the textareas - multiple textareas - of a form.

After much searching and many trials I found a solution while I was preparing this question for S.O. but before I submitted it.  I thought it worth recording here to save time for anyone else with the same problem.  I hope this is an acceptable thing to do on S.O.  If not, moderators, please delete.

In the app I'm working on, users enter text and it is stored in MySQL where each record corresponds to a form.  Users can recall any record for editing, and when they do, they will be presented with the previously-entered data in text areas again to modify. This all works.

Now, I've implemented a search function to search the whole table, and when the user recalls a record, I want to present it in the form for editing, with any and all search hits on a page highlighted - e.g. like this:

[image: multiple selection]
<sub>(source: [informationtamers.com](https://www.informationtamers.com/images/so.png))</sub>
  That's simplified, the actual form is longer, so the user may not notice other hits on the page.

I've made it work with a highlight for the first occurrence of the hit string if it's present in the form, but the problem comes when the string appears multiple times in one text area, or in multiple text areas on the same form.

I have tried these approaches:

- setSelectionRange: This is the only one that even half-way works, but highlights only one string per form.  This makes sense because AFAIK you can't have more than one item selected in an html input field or form and as a UI for someone looking for the results of a search it's not very user-friendly.
- add style at the appropriate points in the input text: `<span style="background-color: yellow">ZZZZ</span>`
  I didn't expect this to work, as it's input in textarea, but I did try it and it just shows the html.  (For the record, the user's data is escaped immediately it's submitted.)
- Invoke the browser's own search facility and pass it the search term. I failed to find any way of doing this on three counts: I can't find a way to trigger Ctrl+f programatically, inject the search term into the browser's search box and initiate the browser search programatically.
- Johann Burkard's 'highlight' jQuery plugin. http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html
  This is capable of highlighting multiple entries on a page, but not in textarea fields, which as far as I can see it ignores.  I believe I've set it up and invoked it correctly, because I can get it to highlight multiple text area captions on the page.  It works by adding `<span class="highlight">Search result</span>`.
- This http://frightanic.com/projects/jquery-highlight/ from frightanic gives results the same as Burkard's plugin.
- This http://www.jquery.info/The-plugin-SearchHighlight  from Renato is targeted at search engine results, so is not my use case.
- This http://jaspreetchahal.org/examples/jquery-onpage-text-highlighter-and-filter.html filters out paragraphs that don't contain a matching string so I didn't try it, but the demo shows that it uses `<span style="background:yellow;color:#000000">Search result</span>` to highlight, like the others, so I doubt it would work on text areas.

Answer (score 0):

- The one that, after some playing around, did what I wanted: http://bebo.minka.name/k2work/libs.js/jquery/2.1.0/highlightTextarea/

Some points to note.

1. The text areas must not be resizable.  The documentation says this, but also documents an option 'resizable' and says that the jQueryUI Resizable is required.  I tried this and it did not work. I guess it was an intention but was not debugged, as the author says he's no longer working on the plugin.
2. I'm using this with colorbox, and found I had to `.highlightTextarea("destroy")` and then `.highlightTextarea("disable")` when user leaves the form, or the highlights appeared when viewing records that had no hits.
3. In some circumstances, the CSS conflicted with mine and messed the form up, so when the user cancels the search, I `.remove` the form from the DOM and rebuild it.  This is probably due to the way I'm using the plugin, and not the best solution, but I couldn't find how else to resolve it.
   The result now seems to be solid, and provides the effect I was trying to find for so long.